# Max value of array won't save ASCII text to file

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I am reading points from a frequency spectrum graph into an array like this:

```
self.iq_fft = self.dofft(self.iq)#Gets values of all data point in block (in dB)
x = self.iq_fft #puts values into x for simplicity
maxi = max(x)
print maxi #This part works fine

def dofft(self, iq):
    N = len(iq)
    iq_fft = scipy.fftpack.fftshift(scipy.fft(iq))
```

Everything works great and it prints out the maximum value of the array to the screen perfect, however, when I try to save the max value to a file, like this:

```
savetxt('myfilelocation', maxi, fmt='%1.4f')#saves max(x) in binary format
```

It ends up saving the binary value to the text file and not the nice pretty ASCII one that printed to the screen. Funny thing is, when I just dump the whole array to a file it looks fine. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`numpy.savetxt` saves an *array* to a file, and it looks like `maxi` is a python Float. It's sort of unusual to use `savetxt` to save a scalar (why not just use Python's built-in file i/o functions?), but if you must, this might work:

```
savetxt('myfilelocation', [maxi], fmt='%1.4f')
```

Notice that I've put `maxi` in a list. Also, make sure that `myfilelocation` doesn't end with a `.gz`. If it does, numpy will compress it. When it doubt, just use `.txt`, or no extension at all.

Comment: Yes, I would also just do `myfile.write("{:1.4}".format(maxi))`